# Trying to limit text output length per line by iterating through each character in a string

Tags: java

I've written this in java and I'm having some trouble.

I am trying to format the line length of the response to a defined limit. My output is several blank lines at the moment. The responses are read in from a seperate ArrayList.

```
private void textLimiter()
{        
        String temp = new String();
        String temp2 = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i < reply.length(); i++){                 
            if(Character.isWhitespace(reply.charAt(i))){
                 index2=i;
                 if((index2 - index3)  < limit){
                    index1 = index2;                         
                }                 

                 if ((index2 - index3) >= limit){                           
                     temp = reply.substring(index3, index1);
                     System.out.println(temp);                        
                     //resets values for next itteration                                                                             
                     index3 = index1;
                }                       

                if(i == reply.length()){
                    temp2 = reply.substring(index3, i);
                    System.out.println(temp2);
                }

            }                

            index3 = 0;
            index2 = 0;
            index1 = 0;


        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: This is what the variables mean:

index1: The last Whitespace found when i is < limit

index2: The current Whitespace found

index3: The start of the line to be printed (so in the first instance of the for loop it will equal 0 as we are starting at the beginning. However when it prints it's first line, it index3 should then equal index1 and start again)

temp: line to be printed when index2 - index3 is >= limit

temp2: last line to be printed when i < limit and == reply.length()

EDIT2
For this section of code I am reading in from a HashMap and reply is a response drawn directly from a hashmap.

Comment: you want to fill up short answer with spaces so that all replies are the same length?!

Comment: You should never need to write `new String()` In fact they should never have added it to the API.  Try `String temp = "";` instead.

Comment: Trying to understand a code which only uses variables named index1, index2, index3, temp1 and temp2 is not very easy. Give your variables a meaningful name. Also, I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you only want to print the first N characters of a String, use substring() and print the result. If what you want is different, then show example inputs and outputs.

Comment: anyway `index3` is always 0 in the first two if statements. i don't really understand your code....

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way:

```
private List<String> textLimiter(String input, int limit) {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (input.length() > limit) {
        returnList.add(input.substring(0, limit);
        input = input.substring(limit, input.length() - limit);
    }
    returnList.add(input);
}
```

Explanation:

1. Get input variables `input` and `limit`.
2. Create a `List<String>`, to store the output.
3. Loop over `input` as long as it is longer as `limit`.
4. (In loop) Add the first limited line to the return list.
5. (In loop) Cut off the first text limited by limit.
6. Add the remaining text to the output.

Then you could call it for example like this:

```
for (String line : textLimiter("This is a test", 4)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This would then print the folowing:

```
This
 is 
a te
st
```

If this is not what you meant, then please add example input and output to your question.

**UPDATE:** As per new requirements, I would do it like this:

```
private List<String> textLimiter(String input, int limit) {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part : parts) {
        if (sb.length() + part.length() > limit) {
            returnList.add(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        sb.append(part + " ");
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        returnList.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Explanation:

1. Get input variables `input` and `limit`.
2. Create a `List<String>` to store the output.
3. Split the `input` on  (white space).
4. Create an empty `StringBuilder sb`.
5. Loop over the array of `parts`.
6. (Loop) If the current content of `sb` + the new `part` would exceed the `limit`, then add the contents of `sb` minus the last  to the `returnList`, and initialize `sb`.
7. (Loop) Always add the current `part` + `" "` to the `sb`.
8. If `sb` still has contents, then add it to the `returnList` aswell.

Calling it again like:

```
for (String line : textLimiter("If you turn left then you should see the corner at the end of the road.", 20)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Output:

```
If you turn left
then you should see
the corner at the
end of the road.
```

Comment: An example input would be "If you turn left then you should see the corner at the end of the road." This will be read in from a hashmap stored in another class. The ideal format is a line of whole words that is less than the limit. Sometimes i require several lines as long as the limit allows.